# Update iOS app from Objective C to Swift

Tags: itunes-store

I have an iOS app which is currently live on AppStore. Now the app needs a major updation both design and functionality. The app is already developed using Xcode 7 and Objective C.

I would like to rebuild the project with Swift code. I am not using core data in app

Can I update the app as a new version of existing live app ?

Comment: Have you done any updates to the app before? Why would this update be any different? The programming language is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, 4 updates had done early, before one year. I would like to rebuild it from the scratch

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. If you will keep same *bundle identifier* as is, there is no doubt it's possible, even if you will build it from the scratch, the itunesconnect will recognize it as the same app. I assume that you should update the version number -like any update should be done- and it should be fine; Regarding to changing the used programming language (from Objective-C to Swift), it would not make any issue.

Comment: You mean that language is not a barrier for the update. Rght?

Comment: That's right. I faced the exact same thing that you are asking about, once you are using the same bundle identifier -as I mentioned in the answer-, you should got the expected result...