# Update Objective-C app to a Swift app

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app in App Store, that was written in Objective-C. Now I developed a Swift project app for the same purpose. Can I replace the Objective-C app to the latest Swift app as like giving an update? A new app is not in mind.

Comment: Yes, you can even mix both language. And why should you not be able to do so.

Comment: My Swift 2 app had an update with the largest reason being *"Updated to include latest Swift language and iOS 10 improvements."* I plan to do this again this year for Swift 4, along with an update for the new App Store. I don't see why you can't keep the same SKU and Product ID for a language update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update iOS app from Objective C to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086614/update-ios-app-from-objective-c-to-swift)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the app is good enough to pass Apple's review guidelines, they don't care which language(s) Xcode compiled to get the result.  You can even submit an update built with a mix of Objective C, C, and Swift.

But users might care if an update is buggier or has less features.  So test.  Also note that (currently) the Swift app bundle may be larger, if that makes any difference to you or your users.